# Could not find io.fabric.tools.gradle:1.+

Tags: android, maven, gradle, twitter-fabric

I am trying to integrate fabric into my android project. I followed the instruction to add fabric from fabric.io. But I facing some issue given below, why this error?

Error:Could not find io.fabric.tools.gradle:1.+:.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/io/fabric/tools/gradle/1.+//1.+-.pom
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/io/fabric/tools/gradle/1.+//1.+-.jar
    https://maven.fabric.io/public/io/fabric/tools/gradle/1.+//1.+-.pom
    https://maven.fabric.io/public/io/fabric/tools/gradle/1.+//1.+-.jar
Required by:
    MyApp:app:unspecified

I have added,

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies{
       classpath 'io.fabric.tools.gradle:1.+'
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you followed [this guide](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/build-tools.html)?

Comment: I have removed mavencentral() line, now it works fine.

Comment: @Annada  how u resolved pls help me

Comment: @Erum if you have repositories{ mavencentral()} somewhere, just remove that line, it worked for me.

Comment: @Erum remove mavencentral() method line is not working

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem. 
The Twitter Kit API document is a little confusing.

I'll recommend install the [Fabric IDE Tool](https://fabric.io/download) and follow it step by step to integrate Fabric.